# IOError(13, 'Permission denied')

Tags: python, error-handling, permissions

I'm running a python program and I cant save any changes and I get this error message... < Function saveFile at 0x31dfb90 >: IOError(13, 'Permission denied')
If you need to know any other info please ask, I need help!
Can anyone tell me how to give the program permission? Or fix the probleme in any other way? Thanks!

Comment: *"I'm running a python program"* Please be more specific here. What exact application are you running? How did you install it? What is the full traceback? What Python version are you running? Etc. etc. Please **edit** your question to include all this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the program tries to save something to a system directory or in a directory you don't have permissions to write.

You have two options:

1. Modify the program in order to save whatever it saves to your home directory where you have write permissions.
2. Run the program with elevated (root) privileges using: `sudo python your_program.py` you will have to provide root's password each time you run the program this way though.

Comment: Option 2 works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please consider then to mark the answer as correct so others can find answers to similar questions.

Comment: I don't know how to.

Comment: You can learn more about how accepting answers works at http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers